# Seems there is no way to access form checkbox's label in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller, checkbox, label

In recently days I am struggling to get my javascript works on get to access a multiple select checkbox's label's value from javascript. I didn't get any success.

When we do a checkbox in form, there is always a value/label pair to show us, value is hidden in small square button for us to click and label is used to show us what is it is.

But unfortunately, in HTML 4.0.1 and html 5, in checkbox properties list, we don't see any thing about the label was kept in checkbox object. So that is why we can not access a checkbox's label value from javascript.

This is a very annoy issue for me right now. I got a set of checkboxes value/label pairs from database, value field was used to hold the item's name and label was used to hold the item's actually value to show my customer to pick up. I have a javascript to help my customer work out how much they have picked up so far. That is why I need javascript to access the label value.

The checkboxes items was generated from DB dynamically, it was put in Spring MVC ModelandView object from controller as Map format. There is a snippet of JSP/Javascript code:

```
<div id="container">
<form:checkboxes id="payment_payForUnits" path="payForUnits" onclick="pickedUnits()" items="${UnitRatePair}" cssStyle="width:40px;" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "payment_payForUnits",widgetType : "dijit.form.MultiSelect",widgetAttrs : {hasDownArrow : true, promptMessage: "<fmt:message key="payment.payforunits.help"/>"}})); 
  function pickedUnits()
  {
    var payForUnits = document.forms[0].payForUnits;
    var txt = "";
    var i;
for (i=0;i<payForUnits.length;i++)
    {
      if (payForUnits[i].checked)
      {
        txt = txt + payForUnits[i].value + " ";
      }
    }
  document.getElementById("payment_paymentReference").value = "You selected: " + txt;
  }
  </script>
</div>
```

If any one get a better idea, please let me know.

Happy new year! Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of access form checkbox attribute, tried access model object directly from javascript successfully. Problem was resolved by simply call:

```
var unitRatepair= '${UnitRatePair}';
```

got fixed.

Hope it is helpful for some one else met similar problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the label/checkbox pairs dynamically, can you give them an id when you add them that lets you link the label and the checkbox?

e.g. iterating i over each checkbox/label pair, set the checkbox id to "checkbox"+i and the label id to "label"+i, so if "checkbox"+i is clicked you can parse out the i and find "label"+i

Comment: Thank you. JSP64. I did my Java development in my past mainly in server side, I am not very well in JSP and Javascript. Could you please give some idea to me how to change my JSP code to let JSP explicitly assign a value to label in my above code snippet please? in Spring MVC, define a multiple select checkboxes, seems don't have to do that, just give the Map to Checkboxes, it will works properly.

Comment: Instead of access form checkbox attribute, tried access model object directly from javascript successfully. Problem was resolved by simply call:

    var unitRatepair= '${UnitRatePair}';

got fixed.

Hope it is helpful for some one else met similar problem.

Cheers!